# AWS WAF and Firewall Manager - Default action when there are no rules applied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-waf, web-application-firewall

Trying to understand what would happen if I were to create a policy in AWS Firewall Manager with no rules applied on the WAF.

Given this policy is applied to a load balancer with a WAF, would the requests received simply be allowed through? Or would WAF block because no rules are applied.

(Trying to understand the functionality of the WAF/FMS policy given no rules are applied, I understand the confusion of putting a WAF there in the first place if no rules are on it)

Resources created:

- AWS WAF Rule Group with a Rule that has no rules applied to it.
  [image]
- AWS Firewall Manager Policy for AWS WAF
  [image]
- Create a new policy and add our rule group above that has no rules.
  [image]
- Add a default Web ACL action of 'allow'
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

> what would happen if I were to create a policy in AWS Firewall Manager with no rules applied on the WAF

By default if you don't have any rules all the requests will be allowed.

If you add some rules only requests with the matching rules will be blocked if you choose to not count it and block it directly.